# How can I conditionally hide last row of Listview inside ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have two `fragments`, which contain lists (`ListView`). In the second `fragment`, each row (despite the last one) contain `checkbox`. The last row contain a different `layout` (`text` + `button`) - that's because I want this to be displayed after the list ends (not at bottom of a screen). What I want to achieve is: when no `checkbox` is checked last row is visible, otherwise last row is invisible. But I haven't find a good solution yet.. I use `getChild()` but this refers only visible items. Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Here is my `getView` method in `ArrayAdapter`:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final int last = this.getCount()-1;
    int theType = getItemViewType(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        if (theType == 0) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.name);
            final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkedDealer);
            checkBox.setTag(position);
            checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(checkBox.isChecked()){
                        checked++;

                        if(checked==1){
                            parent.getChildAt(last).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        checked--;

                        if(checked==0){
                            parent.getChildAt(last).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_search_dealer_footer, null);
        }
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    if (theType == 0) {
        // object item based on the position
        Dealer dealer = data.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(dealer.getName());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the items information in an array, right? So one way to do what you want is to have one boolean field that will be a flag. Each time a checkBox is checked or unchecked you will traverse the array and check if there is any checked value, if it has - set the flag to true else to false. When you have to inflate the last row, you will know if you need to inflate it or return.

Comment: I've tried with boolean flag but it didn't work.. Maybe I was doing it wrong. Inside if(checked==1) I've put: flag=false; notifyDataSetChanged(); And inflate statement in if(theType==1 && flag) but nothing happend. I thought that notifyDataSetChanged calls getView method again but apparently it doesn't. How can I achieve it?